# Why is my slider animation not working transition-grope?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

My animation for the slider is not working. I have used different examples of css styles, but still the transition for the slide does not work. When one of the buttons is pressed, I want to change the slide from right to left or from left to right. what am I doing wrong, who can tell?
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hermann-454hz8

````
 <template>
 <div class="sliderComponent">
     <transition-group  name="slide" tag="div" >
         <div v-for="(item, id ) in items" :key="id">
             <img :src="currentImage" title="image" :alt="item.id" class="slideImage">
         </div>
     </transition-group>
     <div class="controls">
         <button class="prev" @click="prevSlide">d</button>
         <button class="next" @click="nextSlide">b</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 </template>
  ______________
 <style>
 .slideImage {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
  }

 .slider-enter-active,
 .slider-leave-active {
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 }

.slider-enter,
.slider-leave-to {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
 </style>
   ```
````

Comment: Hard to say from only a part of the code. Consider creating a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org)

Comment: @MoritzRingler hi. im add link to sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code does the following:

- there is an array with image urls and you store a current index pointing to the current item
- the current index can be incremented or decremented via buttons (which also happens in an interval)
- for each item, the v-for generates a div
- every div contains an img with the (same!) current src
- the three images are put on top of each other via CSS, so only the last one is visible

You want to add transitions when changing the image using TransitionGroup. According to the [docs for TransitionGroup](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html):

> `<TransitionGroup>` is a built-in component designed for animating the insertion, removal, and order change of elements or components that are rendered in a list.

But you are not changing the array. So there is no change that TransitionGroup could pick up on. Instead, use a regular Transition:

```html
<transition name="slide" v-for="(src, index) in items">
  <img
    v-if="index === currentSlideIndex"
    :src="src"
  />
</transition>
```

Now only the current image is shown, and when the image changes through the v-if, the old image is transitioned out while the new image is transitioned in. Note that the transition class is named `.slide-enter-from`, not just `.slide-enter`.

Here it is a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)